# Where can I start debugging php for the user/create action in the Services module?

Tags: 7, services

I'm trying to create a user via the REST API. I was able to do it successfully using the REST Client Firefox plugin, but when I actually try to call the URL via code, I get no response. No errors, just nothing. I'm trying to debug the PHP (I am a PHP developer), but cannot for the life of me find the point where the code starts.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$('#download_trial').click(function() {
            // also need to create email; can we call rest/user/register from here?
            var name = $('#mail').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:site_url + 'rest/user/token.json',
                type:"POST",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    mytoken = data.token;
                     var data = {
                                "mail":name,
                                "account":{
                                   "name":name,
                                   "pass":generatePassword(),
                                   "mail":name
                                }
                             };

                    $.ajax({
                        url:site_url +'rest/user/create.json',
                        type:"POST",
                        data:data,
                        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": mytoken },
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log("created user");
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                      });
                }
              });

        });
```

The `rest/user/token.json` call is working correctly; I'm able to `console.log` the token that's returned. But from there, it doesn't seem to be hitting the `create.json` function as far as I can see.

I've tried adding a watchdog statement to the `_user_resource_create` function in user_resource.inc, but it never seems to be getting there. What is the initial entry point for the PHP when rest/user/create.json is called, so that I can try debugging it via my IDE debugger?

FYI, this is so that a visitor (non-authenticated user) can create a user account on our system from an external system. Do I need any unusual permissions to allow this?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I think services is looking for a header named `X-CSRF-Token` (not `X-CSRFToken`) if that helps

Comment: I'll see if that makes a difference; when I worked with Django it was spelled without the extra hypen, so that's habit.

Comment: Fixed the token header, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made any difference. Still not getting anything back, and isn't hitting the create function that I can see.

Comment: Do a `POST` to '?q=rest/user.json` instead, and send along something like `{ name: 'bob', mail: 'bob@hotmail.com' }`. Or just use the `user_register()` function provided by jDrupal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jDrupal; will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, do you mean 'q=rest/user/create.json'? There is no resource in Services that's just 'user'.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein - in the interest of not having to install extra libraries, I tried your first suggestion, and get "["Missing required argument account"]" back. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind; I got it. I was sending json instead of x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Correct, there is no 'create' resource, however services automatically routes it based on the HTTP method. In the case of POST, that means create, PUT means UPDATE, etc.